# Thevenin's Resistance

Tags: resistance, thevenin

[image]

I can't understand why the answer is like in the picture and not R = [ ( 4 + 6 ) // 8 ] + 2.
Isn't 4 in series with 6 and parallel to 8 ?

Comment: Try drawing the current paths from the node just above the arrow to the node just below the arrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow the below steps. Naming the nodes is usually useful to see the next step.

[image]

6th step is 4+2=6